# How to update the entire ObservableCollection with JSON from API in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I have a mobile app with 3 listview inside 3 frame respectively. When i open the app for the first time it appears normal(the 3 listview contains the task lists), but when i accept one task it has to be in the "pending list", in other listview:

```
public async Task obtenerTareas(string idAgente)
{
  
    try
    {
    
        // URL de la API que proporciona la lista de tareas
        string apiUrl = "https://tareas.sistemaonline.com.ar/rest-api/AgentesRetails?agenteRetailGET=" + idAgente;

        // Crear una instancia de HttpClient
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Realizar una solicitud HTTP GET a la API
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

        // Si la solicitud fue exitosa
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Leer el contenido de la respuesta como una cadena JSON
            string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Deserializar la cadena JSON en una lista de objetos de tipo Tarea
            ObservableCollection<Tarea> tareas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< ObservableCollection < Tarea >>(jsonContent);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Lista.Clear(); // Limpia la lista existente
                foreach (var tarea in tareas)
                {
                    tarea.mes = "" + Convert.ToDateTime(tarea.fecha_sol).ToString("MMMM").Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + "";
                    tarea.dia = "  " + Convert.ToDateTime(tarea.fecha_sol).ToString("dd") + "  ";
                   // Agrega elementos a la lista existente
                }
                Lista = tareas;
            });
       
        }
        else
        {
            // Si la solicitud no fue exitosa, manejar el error según sea necesario
            await appNotificacionesPush.App2.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error al cargar las tareas" + response.StatusCode, "ok", "ok");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await appNotificacionesPush.App2.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error" + ex.Message, "ok", "ok");

    }
 
}
```

But the lists don't update itself after accepting someone.

```
public static ICommand RefrescarCommand { get; private set; }


private bool _esRefrescando;

public bool EsRefrescando
{
    get { return _esRefrescando; }
    set
    {
        if (_esRefrescando != value)
        {
            _esRefrescando = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EsRefrescando));
        }
    }
}
public string nombre {  get; set; }
 
private ObservableCollection<Tarea> _lista;

public ObservableCollection<Tarea> Lista
{
    get { return _lista; }
    set
    {
        if (_lista != value)
        {
            _lista = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Lista));
        }
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<Tarea> _listaC;

public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasCurso
{
    get { return _listaC; }
    set
    {
        if (_listaC != value)
        {
            _listaC = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasCurso));
        }
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<Tarea> _listaP;

public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasPendientes
{
    get { return _listaP; }
    set
    {
        if (_listaP != value)
        {
            _listaP = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasPendientes));
        }
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
public MvTareas()
{
    this.nombre = "Hola" + Preferences.Get("usuario", "");
    Lista = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
    ListaTareasPendientes = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
    ListaTareasCurso = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
    obtenerTareas(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
    obtenerTareasP(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));

    obtenerTareasC(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
    RefrescarCommand = new Command(ActualizarTareas);


}

public async void ActualizarTareas()
{
    await obtenerTareas(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
    await obtenerTareasP(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
 
    await obtenerTareasC(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        EsRefrescando = false;
    });

}
```

Edit: my xaml file with itemsource:

```
 <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" HeightRequest="300">

     <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     
         <Label Text="Tareas Disponibles" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,10" />



         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Lista}" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <ViewCell>
...
```

Comment: what is the `ItemsSource` of the lists bound to?  Does your VM class actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Leer el contenido de la respuesta como una cadena JSON
            string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Deserializar la cadena JSON en una lista de objetos de tipo Tarea
            ObservableCollection<Tarea> tareas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< ObservableCollection < Tarea >>(jsonContent);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Lista.Clear(); // Limpia la lista existente
                foreach (var tarea in tareas)
                {
                    tarea.mes = "" + Convert.ToDateTime(tarea.fecha_sol).ToString("MMMM").Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + "";
                    tarea.dia = "  " + Convert.ToDateTime(tarea.fecha_sol).ToString("dd") + "  ";
                   // Agrega elementos a la lista existente
                }
                Lista = tareas;
            });
```

From the code you posted above, we could find that you're trying to assign another address to `Lista` that another object points to(`tareas`) with code   `Lista = tareas;`. This should be what causes the data not to be refreshed.

You can try traversing list `tareas` and adding the elements to `Lista` one by one. Just as follows:

```
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Lista.Clear(); // Limpia la lista existente
            foreach (var tarea in tareas)
            {
                tarea.mes = "" + Convert.ToDateTime(tarea.fecha_sol).ToString("MMMM").Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + "";
                tarea.dia = "  " + Convert.ToDateTime(tarea.fecha_sol).ToString("dd") + "  ";
               // Agrega elementos a la lista existente


            // add each element to Lista one by one
             Lista.Add(tarea);

            }

           // comment out the following code
           //Lista = tareas;
        });
```

Comment: it doesn't function. when i accept a task is not refreshing

Comment: `when i accept a task is not refreshing`  Have you tried my code? If it is convenient for you, could you please post the full code of `yourpage.xaml` and `View Model` ?